# Android Espresso : How to perform an action when the view is displayed on the screen?

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I want to add instrumental tests to my Android app.

There is a login screen that perform a load to a certain data first and when succeed it display to the user the auth. forms (username+password).

I want to perform an action to the EditText widgets like **typeText** like below:

```
    @Test
    fun agnetlogin() {

        onView(withId(R.id.edt_login)).perform(typeText(loginToBeTyped), closeSoftKeyboard())
        onView(withId(R.id.edt_password)).perform(typeText(passwordToBeTyped), closeSoftKeyboard())

        onView(withId(R.id.btn_sign_in)).perform(click())
    }
```

but I get the error that the views doesn't exit in hierarchy and it's normal because the visibilities is set to gone when data is charging.

Answer (score 0):

@J.M.J, the good practice to check whether the view is displayed in the view or not. It also avoids errors, you can check for whether the view is displayed or not as below example.

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_view))
    .perform(click())
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

or if you know that the view is already presented, you can check with a specific name like

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_view))
    .check(matches(withText("Hello Espresso!")))
    .perform(click())
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an Idlingrecource manager which will wait until your input fields are loaded before performing actions on them:

https://medium.com/azimolabs/wait-for-it-idlingresource-and-conditionwatcher-602055f32356

A quick and dirty solution might be to put a sleep (e.g. for 5 seconds) in front of your code:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);

onView(withId(R.id.my_view))
.perform(click())
.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```